# SSRS - display design mode when accessing report through report server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to display the field names  from dataset bound to each column on the report. Is there an option in SSRS to display the report in design mode when you run the report through report viewer?
Or are there any other suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You might want to try describing your problem better or adding some screen shots, because I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish so probably nobody else does either. Are you just trying to add headers?

Comment: I am trying to show the field names from dataset that is bound to the columns. Is it possible to display this when you run the report?

Comment: Can you post your query? I think I know what your problem is...

Comment: SELECT name, age FROM Members.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Sorry man!